# Cannot read property 'on' of null conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a script that works fine until I add another script. When the other script is added I get the console error.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of null at mapForm
```

I'm integrating my own script with JotForm so I have a couple libraries loading. I tried to set a no conflict without luck.

```
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js

function mapForm() {    
  var JotFirst = document.getElementById("first_4"),
      ACFirst = document.getElementById("firstname");
        JotFirst.addEventListener('input', function() {
            ACFirst.value = JotFirst.value;
        }); 
  var JotLast = document.getElementById("last_4"),
      ACLast = document.getElementById("lastname");
        JotLast.addEventListener('input', function() {
            ACLast.value = JotLast.value;
        });
      JotProd = $("input[type='checkbox'][id='input_5_1000']");
      ACProd = $("input[type='checkbox'][id='extra_mf_1_515']");
        JotProd.on("change", function() {
            ACProd.prop("checked", this.checked);
        }); 
    $("#input_5_custom_1000_0").change(function() {     
        var el = $(this) ;      
        if(el.val() === "Option Two" ) {
        document.getElementById("extra_mf_3_516").selectedIndex = "1";
        }
        else if(el.val() === "Option Three" ) {
        document.getElementById("extra_mf_3_516").selectedIndex = "2";
        }   
    }); 
}
window.onload = mapForm;
```

The above code works fine on it's own.

```
https://cdn.jotfor.ms/static/prototype.forms.js
https://cdn.jotfor.ms/static/jotform.forms.js
```

When these are introduced my script stops working. I've searched and searched and tried everything I know to solve.

Here's the page in question: https://btwebnetwork.com/scripts/multi-submission-form/AllClients.php

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I got lazy. In a hurry this morning. I will edit further if needed. Really hoping to get this figured out.

Comment: if you `console.log` your `JotProd` variable after setting it, what do you see ?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of null
    at window.onload (AllClients.php:72)

Comment: (I meant before to call `on()` onto the variable). You probably have no element in your DOM that satisfies the filter you're using (e.g. `input[type='checkbox'][id='input_5_1000']`). And I suggest you use `$('#input_5_1000')` instead, it's more readable and you're supposed to only have one single element for a given id.

Comment: The error is only thrown when the presence of the other library and function are called. Otherwise it works. I've moved on to another solution for now.

Comment: Please consider to choose the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure taht the `JotProd` variable is not `NULL`, you can do it like this

```
if(JotProd){
    JotProd.on("change", function() {
        ACProd.prop("checked", this.checked);
    }); 
}
```

Comment: I did try a variant of this, but likely mistwrote it. I'll try again when I get back to work. Thnx

Comment: Actually that did work! Now it's a another error. I will try to get this worked out the same way. I DID try this method but I must have been writing the code correctly OR overlooked that it was a separate issues after the fact.

Comment: *that solution effectively broke the function though.

Comment: I appreciate your feedback. The error was thrown when the second library was called and I wasn't able to work out the conflict.

Comment: @jarmerson Is this still an issue?